# DynamoDB: Conditional check on Global Secondary Index in Write Transaction

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table which is tracking two IDs:

- The first ID (*A*) is used as the partition and sort key of the records in the table, and is generated randomly when the record is saved.
- The second ID (*B*) is not randomly generated, and is tracking an entity in another system.  There should only ever be one record with a unique *B* in the table (effectively the second ID field would have a `UNIQUE` constraint if this was SQL).

This table has a Global Secondary Index, with the partition key set to *B* and the sort key set to *A*; acting as a reverse lookup for the records that are in the main table.

I would like to put a record into this main table, but only do so if there's no record with *B* already present.  Specifically, I'd like to:

1. Check that *B* doesn't exist in the GSI
2. Call out to another system to do something
3. Put a record with *B* and a randomly generated *A*

Is this possible using DynamoDB transactional writes?  From looking at the documents, there is a ConditionCheck operation that could be useful here; but as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem possible to run a condition check on a GSI, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do transactions that include GSIs. I would recommend you follow the design of this blog post, putting an entry in the base table with B as the primary key to enable the uniqueness check (maybe then using it instead of a GSI):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/